# Box2D Body cannot be serialized. How to ignore or serialize it successfully?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, serialization

In my game, which implements the network functionality with Kryonet, I would like to send a class ("MyBox2DComponent") over the network which e.g. contains a field of type Body (Box2D).

Of course I registered the classes in Kryo:

```java
kryo.register(MyBox2DComponent.class);
kryo.register(Body.class);
kryo.register(Fixture.class);
```

Unfortunately this fails as Kryo seems to find itself in an infinite serialization loop:

```java
body (com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture)
items (com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array)
fixtures (com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body)
body (com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture)
items (com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array)
fixtures (com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body)
body (com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture)
items (com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array)
fixtures (com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body)
body (my.package.MyBox2DComponent)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ReflectField.write(ReflectField.java:92)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:107)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:561)
...
```

How can I fix this?
Can I exclude certain fields from serialization (would be fine for me here in this example),
or is there some other way I can help Kryo with that?

Comment: Can you clarify why you're trying to send an instance of this class in the first place? It would be more conventional to send a message *about* this instance, like "Spawn entity based on prefab 42 at coordinates X Y Z and call it Q" or "Move entity Q to coordinates X Y Z" - note that in these cases, all that's going over the wire are simple numbers, not complex structures containing a potentially cyclical graph of references. If the operation you want to perform can be rephrased this way, it's likely to go much more smoothly for you - plus improve security & reduce bandwidth usage as a bonus!

Comment: Hey @DMGregory, sure: So what you describe is my current approach: I let the server create and spawn an entity in my ECS and then send to the clients a message called "SpawnByPrefabNameMsg" (where "Prefabs" here means a kind of builder class is; this describes an entity with its components). However, I would like more flexibility and I thought it would be nicer to be able to send a message for each entity on the server side containing a list of its components. So I could also spawn entities that are already adjusted and do not correspond to a "blueprint" on the clients.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any "best-practice" instructions for ECS with networking that I could use as a reference for a successful architecture/pattern.

Comment: That's fine, but then what you're sending across the wire is not the live component wired up on the entity. You're sending a set of instructions for how to set up that component. So that should probably be a distinct data type, rather than trying to serialize the live component directly.

Comment: Ah okay! So you mean for a generic approach, should I have a "blueprint component" for each component and then send it in each case?

Comment: It might not be a separate type for each component. It could also be a generic data structure that contains a component ID and a list of parameters and values, or a list of indices of setter functions to invoke, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134804/discussion-between-echtfettigerkeks-and-dmgregory).